# PHP save array made of dictionary items into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dictionary

I’m trying to save an array in PHP to a table in MySQL database.
My PHP receives an array in json format. The array is made up of a list of dictionaries as following:

```
{ 
{“first_name” : “Sam”, “last_name”: “Smith”, “email”: sam.smith@domain.com}, 
{“first_name” : “Mike”, “last_name”: “Detman”, “email”: mike.detman@domain.com}, 
{“first_name” : “Linda”, “last_name”: “Bennett”, “email”: linda.bennett@domain.com}}
```

The question is what is the simplest way to save this into the database table with the corresponding columns for keys “first_name”, “last_name”, and “email”?

Many answers on the web suggest using php function serialize(). But this method seems to work for saving only one column into the table, so may not be working for saving records multiple columns. (I might be wrong…..)

Others suggest using query “INSERT INTO table (…) VALUES(….)”. But this method seems to be working for adding a single record.
Can anybody suggest a way to realize the task? Thank you!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Thanks for your input so far... Here is my Php Code trying to use loop (I'm so dummy on PHP, so please don't laugh if you see anything nonsense....)

```
$receivedData= json_decode($json_data);

$dbc=mysql_connect("mysql", "Username", "Passcode");
mysql_select_db("ObtainedData");

while ($lineData = mysql_fetch_array($receivedData))
{
$firstName = $lineData['first_name'];
$lastName = $lineData['last_name'];
$email= $lineData['email'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO aData (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ($lastName, $firstName, $email)");
}
```

Is this the right way to do? Am I using the right loop way or need other way? Also do I need to serialize() the data before doing the loop?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Ok, here is my latest version, still no data go into the database yet. However, based on the time it takes to receive the response, it seems that the loop was executed. And the response was right with the complete data... Not knowing if there are any issues with the database setup or table settings?

```
<?php

$json_data=file_get_contents('php://input', true);
$post_data = json_decode($json_data);
$dbc=mysql_connect("mysql", "username", "passcode");
mysql_select_db("ObtainedData");

foreach($post_data as $lineData)
{$first_name=$lineData->first_name;
 $last_name=$lineData->last_name;
 $email=$lineData->email;
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'aData' ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email') VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')");}

if (is_array($post_data))
$response = array("status" => "ok", "code" => 0, "original request" => $post_data);
else
$response = array("status" => "error", "code" => -1, "original_request" => $post_data);
$processed = json_encode($response);
echo $processed;

mysql_close($dbc);

?>
```

Comment: use `json_decode` and loop on the results to construct sql insert queries

Comment: Split your data by ":"  to prepare a list or any other data structure of PHP and then use odd index for column name and even indexes for  their corresponding values. With this data you can make the SQL query which do your job.

Comment: @Code-Monk what??!! do you mean parsing the json string manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Others suggest using query “INSERT INTO table (…) VALUES(….)”. But this method seems to be working for adding a single record.

No it can work for multiple records:

```sql
insert into `table`
  (`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`)  
values 
  ('row 1 first name', 'row 1 last name', 'row 1 email'),
  ('row 2 first name', 'row 2 last name', 'row 2 email') ...
```

To construct the query, you need to use `json_decode` on the json string and loop on the results row by row to construct a tuple, you can use `array_map` to return a tuple for every record + `implode` to concatenate all tuples (if you don't like loops)

#### Edit

**(1)**
`json_decode` here will result in an array of objects not an array of associative arrays because simply json objects are converted to PHP `stdClass` objects (you can't say `$lineData['first_name']`, only `$lineData->first_name` is allowed), if you really want to access a property in an object in the same way you do with arrays like `$lineData['first_name']`, then you have to convert the result to an associative array using `json_decode($json_data, true)`

**(2)**
Your loop is O.K but requires little modification:

1. `$receivedData` is already an array with n elements, the correct way to loop through an array in PHP is like that:
   `foreach($receivedData as $lineData)`
   the line you are using : `while ($lineData = mysql_fetch_array($receivedData))` is used to loop through a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) (the one you get when you use `mysql_query` with a select statement)
2. Always enclose table names and columns with backticks like that `` INSERT INTO `aData` (`first_name`, `last_name`... `` so that no conflicts happen if the name is a reserved keyword
3. MySQL strings must be enclosed in single or double quotes, so the correct query should look like: 
   `` mysql_query("INSERT INTO `aData` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES ('$lastName', '$firstName', '$email'))" ``

Comment: I have to use loops because the array contains 1000+ records inside. I have already used decode($json_data) to turn the data into array in PHP.

Comment: `array_map` + `implode` will do the same thing internally with a loop, any way, do you need help in that part?

Comment: Could you? I have just updated my post, if you could suggest the right way to code the php that will very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PaulLian I updated the answer based on your edit, don't hesitate to ask about any part

Comment: I just updated the code as you suggested, not working yet, but feels like getting closer. Could you take a look again?

Comment: @PaulLian your code looks o.k except your query, I'll just repeat what I have said in my post :D, enclose sql values in single/double quotes **(')** / **(")** and backticks **(`)** for table names and columns names, this should fix the problem

Comment: Wonderful! I just changed the ' around sql values into `, it works! Thanks a lot Man! :D Cheers.....